# Count Values in a column and add the result next to the column in a new one

Tags: r

I have a fairly large dataset and want to count how often the value is mentioned in a specific column

Example:

```
A Home Away 
D Lisa Jill
D Jack Andre
C Jack Kirk
C Jane Jill
```

I want to add a new column (called Count) and count how often every name in Home is mentioned.

```
A Home Away Count
D Lisa Jill 1
D Jack Andre 2
C Jack Kirk 2
C Jane Jill  1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Or using `plyr` (suppose your data is placed in `df`):

```
library(plyr)
join(df, as.data.frame(table(Home=df$Home)))

#   A Home  Away Freq
# 1 D Lisa  Jill    1
# 2 D Jack Andre    2
# 3 C Jack  Kirk    2
# 4 C Jane  Jill    1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'Home', get the number of rows (`n()`) and create that as new column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>%
   group_by(Home) %>%
   mutate(Count = n())
#    A  Home  Away Count
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     D  Lisa  Jill     1
#2     D  Jack Andre     2
#3     C  Jack  Kirk     2
#4     C  Jane  Jill     1
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Count := .N, by = Home]
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Count <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(Home), Home, FUN = length))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - I am still a noob in R and got following error: invalid factor level, NAs generated

Comment: @C.H.  Is it based on the `ave` or `dplyr`.  I think the `dplyr` should work fine.

Comment: @C.H.  Updated the `ave` method.  Please check if that still gives error

Comment: No Error Message but can not find the new column "count"

Comment: @C.H.  If you are mentioning about the dplyr, it has to be assigned to the original object `df <- df %>% group_by...` or use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`.  For the other cases, it is assigned.